# Getting data- value from sender in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to create a lightbox component in Polymer, with it's child items being multiple `<img>` tags. These will have an `src`, which is a thumbnail and a `data-fullimage` attribute, which will contain the path to the full size image.

In the Polymer component, I've set the on-click tag on the image content selector, and any Javascript calls using `sender.xyz` return the `content` tag, not the image tag, thus not allowing me to retrieve the path to the full image. Is there any way to get the `data-fullimage` of the image that is clicked, or even the `src` value if need be?

**Polymer Component**

```
imageClick: function(event, detail, sender) 
{
      console.log(sender);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
<paper-lightbox>
    <img src="img/one.png" data-fullimage="img/one-large.png"></img>
    <img src="img/two.png" data-fullimage="img/two-large.png"></img>
</paper-lightbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to put click handlers on the `img` tags. Moreover this doesn't work, because they are not bound to functions in the `paper-lightbox` element. What you want is

```
event.path[0].getAttribute("data-fullimage")
```

But this only works if your light DOM elements consist of exactly one element. If your light DOM elements are more complex, but it should be possible to click them anywhere, use this expression instead

```
event.path[[].indexOf.call(event.path, sender) - 1].getAttribute("data-fullimage")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML:**

```
<paper-lightbox>
   <img src="img/one.png" on-tap="{{imageTap}}" data-fullimage="img/one-large.png"></img>
   <img src="img/two.png" on-tap="{{imageTap}}" data-fullimage="img/two-large.png"></img>
</paper-lightbox>
```

**JS:**

```
imageTap: function(sender){
    var fullImage = sender.target.attributes["data-fullimage"];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. I tried logging it but that doesn't show either. The JS goes within the Polymer() script, right?

Comment: You have a typo in your coment (lowercase "t"). This should work. If you have some polymer element that contains <paper-lighbox> and listener for event is in its javascript

Comment: If it is not inside any element. You should look for `document.addEventLister`

Comment: Yes, I have a <polymer-element> for the paper-lightbox and I put the imageTap function within the Polymer({}); part of it

Comment: And it does not even go in the listener? Can you post on jsbin or elsewhere more of your code. I can not see what is wrong here